MinIO Docker Compose не хочет работать https
MinIO настроен через Docker Compose:
version: '3.3'

services:
  minio:
    image: bitnami/minio:latest
    ports:
      - "9000:9000"
      - "9001:9001"
    volumes:
      - .minio:/minio
      - ./certs:/certs
    environment:
      MINIO_ROOT_USER: "minioadmin"
      MINIO_ROOT_PASSWORD: "minioadmin"
      MINIO_ADDRESS: ":9000"
      MINIO_CONSOLE_ADDRESS: ":9001"
    healthcheck:
      test: [ "CMD", "mc", "ready", "local" ]
      interval: 5s
      timeout: 5s
      retries: 5

Я пробовал выставлять MINIO_SERVER_URL=https://localhost:9000, MINIO_SCHEME=https, все равно не принимает подключения.
Сертификаты создаю через openssl:
openssl req -new -x509 -days 3650 -key private.key -out public.crt ...

Пробовал создавать сертификаты по документации через certgen и перемещать файлы с /cert -> /cert/CAs все равно не работает.

попробуйте поднять сервис traefik/nginx и проксируйте через него все внешние сервисы, это избавит вас от проблем с сертификатами, это так же избавит вас от головной боли когда все сервисы имеют разный API для тех или иных функций, а будет единый интерфейс.

Решил по-другому. Для тех, кто хочет создать соединенное подключение между вашими приложениями:
version: '3'

services:
  minio:
    image: minio/minio
    ports:
      - "9000:9000"
      - "9001:9001"
    volumes:
      - ./minio/data:/data
      - ./minio/certs:/certs
    environment:
      MINIO_ROOT_USER: minioadmin
      MINIO_ROOT_PASSWORD: minioadmin
      MINIO_SCHEME: https
      SSL_CERT_FILE: /certs/public.crt
    command: server --console-address ":9001" /data --certs-dir /certs

volumes:
  minio_storage: {}

